# horizontal scrolling issue with color box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using color box for a modal popup now theres a link and when user clicks on that link a modal is displayed. for the contents of the modal I am pointing to a URL.

```
<div class="content">

<a class="Modal" href="http://yahoo.com" onclick="openModal();">Click Here   </a>

</div>
```

The problem is since its a url there are horizontal and vertical scrollbars in the modal I just want vertical scrollbars I tired something like

```
<style type="test/css">#cboxLoadedContent{overflow-x:hidden !important;} </style>
```

but doesnt work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#cboxLoadedContent{overflow-x:hidden !important;}
```

That looks like it should work.  Are you sure the scrollbars are on #cboxLoadedContent and not some child element?

Comment: those child elements are inside #cboxLoadedContent so I am hoping the child elements should get that style too

Comment: They would not.  That style only applies to #cboxLoadedContent.  For example, if you wanted to apply it to all child elements, you could do something like this: #cboxLoadedContent * { overflow-x:hidden; }

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that colorbox is inheriting some extra padding from your general site stylesheet. Without seeing a live link I can only suggest hunting around in firebug from element to element to see some padding, margin, border or width that is inherited from your general stylesheet - maybe on the img element.

If you're using any general !important declarations they can often override the specifically styles that lightboxes serve up.